# why [Circular] is getting added in the hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

here is my code

```
db.query(str, arr, function selectCb(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                return proceed(false, {errno:'010',message:error.message}, request);
            }
            var q = async.queue(function (results, callback) {
                // add the gib infor
                if (results.refertype=='G') {
                    var input={};
                    input.fields="*";
                    input.gibname=results.refername;
                    gib.getgibinternal(input, makeCallback(i));
                    function makeCallback(index) {
                        return function(gresult) {
                            results.gib=gresult.data[0];
                            callback(results);
                        }
                    }
                    // add the user info        
                } else if(results.refertype=='U') {
                    var input={};
                    input.username=results.refername;
                    input.fields="*";
                    user.getuserinternal(input, makeCallbackuser(i));
                    function makeCallbackuser(index) {
                        return function(gresult) {
                            results.user=gresult.data[0];
                            callback(results);
                        }
                    }
                } 

            }, results.length);
            // assign a callback
            q.drain = function() {
                return proceed(true, self.results, self.request);
            }
            self.results=results;

            for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
                // the first console
                console.log(results[i]);
                // add some items to the queue
                q.push(results[i], function (results) {
                     results[i]=results;
                     self.results[i]=results;
                                    //the second console.
                    console.log(results);
                });
            }
            if (results.length==0) {
                return proceed(true, results, request);
            }  
        });
```

The out put of above code is :

```
// the first console
{ cardid: 30,
  cardtype: 'I',
  status: 'A',
  refername: 'admin',
  refertype: 'U' }
// the second console 
{ '1': [Circular],
  cardid: 30,
  cardtype: 'I',
  status: 'A',
  refername: 'admin',
  refertype: 'U',
  user:
   { name: 'admin',
     username: 'admin',
     deleted: 'N' } }
```

how  this  `'1': [Circular],` get added .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit:

```
q.push(results[i], function (results) {
```

is the same as this (with some renaming to make it easier to track the scope):

```
q.push(self.results[i], function(r) {
    r[i] = r; // <------------------- Look at me!
    self.results[i] = r;
    //the second console.
    console.log(r);
});
```

The `self.results[i]` change just comes from the `self.results=results;` right above your `for` loop. The interesting part is this:

```
    r[i] = r;
```

If `i` is 1 you will have added a property named `1` to `r` whose value is `r` itself, hence the `[Circular]`. I would hazard a guess that `results.length` is 2 and that your function is acting as a closure over `i` and ending up with using the last value that `i` had and that's why you get the `'1'` rather than a `'0'` property.

I see three main Things that could be causing you trouble:

- The classic closure problem with `i`.
- Too many things were called `results` so it was easy to lose track of which one you were working with.
- The circular reference: `r[i] = r;`.

Another possible source of confusion is that `results` and `self.results` are the same object but that might be okay.

Comment: with ref. to your answer i changed q.push(results[i], function (r) {
     results[i]=r;
     self.results[i]=results[i];
    }); and it working now

Comment: @Rahul: cool, and the `i` ends up with te right value? I ask because I'm not sure when that function will get called.

Comment: Yeah output is coming right , m using https://github.com/caolan/async#queue queue here

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a circular reference and console.log is muffling it. Try doing `console.log(Object.keys(results['1']));` for more information on what's inside the Object `1`